# No titles on windows in activities overview (GNOME 3.26)

Tags: interface, gnome-shell, activities-overview

As you can see on image there is still a label on active window, but no labels on others, witch makes quite hard to navigate in activity view, especially when there are many windows (in this form they are almost indistinguishable from each other).

[image]

I was lazy to install a new OS instance to see if it is my system’s bug or a built-in feature, so I just watched videos on YouTube to figure out if someone else has such a problem. Apparently, this issue was introduced in version 3.24, since all videos I watched with this version were affected by this flaw, while in previous versions the names were displayed on all windows as usual.

So my question is: is it possible to fix that and make every window have its own title regardless of the focus?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [release notes for Gnome 3.26](https://wiki.gnome.org/ThreePointTwentyfive/ReleaseNotes) this was an intentional change:

> Refined activities overview - window titles now shown on hover and spacings have been adjusted to give larger window thumbnails. This gives a cleaner view and results in larger window thumbnails, making it easier to pick the window you want.

One could probably change this by writing a gnome shell extension.